# Is it possible with SQL to get all tables from a database using LIKE and then change column size in them all

Tags: sql, liquibase, alter-table

Is it possible to get all tables in a database with LIKE for example table containing 'TOTAL%' and then save these to some variable, then use them in another query to change column size for them all like

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLE1, TABLE2 TABLE3, ...{Use tables from previous query}]
ALTER COLUMN [Salary] VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple tables with the same schema anyway

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Use a numeric data type for salary. E.g. `decimal(12,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to get the desired effect using CURSORS.
The code may be look like this

```
DECLARE @tableName nvarchar(128), @command nvarchar(max)

DECLARE tableCursor CURSOR STATIC FOR 
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name LIKE 'TOTAL%'

OPEN tableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO @tableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @command = 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' ALTER COLUMN [Salary] VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL'
    EXEC sp_executesql @command
    FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO @tableName
END

CLOSE tableCursor
DEALLOCATE tableCursor
```